# Sequelize how to insert update multiple row?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I try to insert multiple row inside my database with Sequelize but the for loop get stuck due to some constraint violation.

```
        let dataset = [
             ["2016-01-01","987"],
             ["2016-01-02","987"],
             ["2016-01-03","987"],
             ["2016-01-04","987"],
             ["2016-01-05","987"],
             ["2016-01-06","987"],
             ["2016-01-07","987"],
             ...
        ];
        for(let row of dataset) {       
            model.findOrCreate({
                where: {date_prc: row[0]},
                defaults: {value: row[1]}
            });
        }
```

When I look to the SQL log it is checking if the date is already inserted and if it not it is trying to insert the row. But in some case, instead to insert the missing date row, it's inserting the next date.

for example in the log I see:

```
 select 2016-01-03 // this one is missing
 select 2016-01-04 // this one is not missing
 insert 2016-01-04 // it is inserting 2016-01-04 instead of 2016-01-03
```

Comment: You have the `updateOnDuplicate` option for `bulkCreate`.

Comment: @Adam would bulkcreate work for 100000 entries at once? (I can't try right now... :-/ )

Comment: @Adam postgres does not support the 'ignoreDuplicates' option